# Making time series with set of dates and times (and calculate the frequency)

Tags: r

I am kinda new to R and would be needing your help on a issue.

The dataset I have is such that I have a csv file with 1 row in which the date and time is given. It looks something like this:

Date and Time (dd-mm-yyyy)

```
12-3-2018 08:51 
12-3-2018 08:36
12-3-2018 09:21
12-3-2018 11:32
```

The dataset has almost 200.000 rows and some dates and times are identical. What I want to do is to look the data something like this:

Date and Time (dd-mm-yyyy), Amount of times

```
12-3-2018 08:36, 2
12-3-2018 08:51, 4
12-3-2018 09:21, 3
12-3-2018 11:32, 2
```

So I want to order all the dates (13th comes after 12th and so on) and I want to write the amount of times the data and time was seen next to it (in a time series)

Can you please suggest some methods?

Thank you very much in advance!

RC

Note: I tried the arrange method, but that doesn't arrange the dates quite well and it doesn't take into account that some dates and times are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `table`

```
table(df1$datetime)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, there is `count` function

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    count(datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it orders with the amount of observations! Do you know how I can put this in a regression? In a way that I can assign the value zero to times that aren't observed.

Comment: @rc. If you also need the combinations that are not observed.  I would create a sequence of dates in`complete`, i.e. `df1 %>% count(datetime) %>% complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = '1 hour'), fill = list(n = 0))`. You can change the `by` according to your needs